# P/Invoke with LibraryImport, problem with byte array and its in/out length attributes marshalling

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have a function defined with the old `[DllImport]` as follows and it works nicely

```cs
[DllImport("tbs.dll", EntryPoint = "Tbsip_Submit_Command", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern uint Tbsip_Submit_Command(
 IntPtr context,
 uint locality,
 uint priority,
 [In] byte[] inBuffer,
 uint inBufferSize,
 [Out] byte[] outbuf,
 ref uint outBufLen
);
```

I would like to turn this definition to use the source generation way with `LibraryImport`. However, I run into problems with `outBuf` and `outBufLen`.

```cs
[LibraryImport("tbs", EntryPoint = "Tbsip_Submit_Command",StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]
internal static partial uint Tbsip_Submit_Command(
    IntPtr context,
    uint locality,
    uint priority,
    in byte[] inBuffer,
    uint inbufferSize,
    out byte[] outbuf,
    ref uint outBufLen
);
```

I think the error message is fairly descriptive of what should be done. But I do not know how and if that "how" is the right thing to do.

> Error SYSLIB1051  Marshalling an array from unmanaged to managed requires either the 'SizeParamIndex' or 'SizeConst' fields to be set on a 'MarshalAsAttribute' or the 'ConstantElementCount' or 'CountElementName' properties to be set on a 'MarshalUsingAttribute'. The generated source will not handle marshalling of parameter 'outbuf'

But then if I try something like

```cs
[LibraryImport("tbs", EntryPoint = "Tbsip_Submit_Command",StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]
internal static partial uint Tbsip_Submit_Command(
    IntPtr context,
    uint locality,
    uint priority,
    in byte[] inBuffer,
    uint inbufferSize,
    [MarshalUsing(CountElementName = "outBufLen")] out byte[] outbuf,
    ref uint outBufLen
);
```

The compiler stops complaining. However, the call does not work, as the marshaller throws

> System.ArgumentException: 'Destination is too short. (Parameter 'destination')'

Does anyone have have ideas as to how to handled this in/out situation? The purpose or `outBufLen` is both to tell the ingoing buffer length and then as a return value how many bytes was written to the buffer.

Comment: `[Out] byte[] outbuf` means you're passing a pointer to an array that the .NET side has already allocated and you expect the native side to fill. `out byte[] outbuf` means you're passing a pointer to a pointer to an array that will be allocated and filled by the native side. They are quite semantically (and at binary level) different.

Comment: I think I understand what you write. Though I suppose I need to gear back to this issue and consider what could be the solution for this particular case. I think this is not as complex as some other cases could be (e.g. passing structures), but perhaps helpful as a case to consider those too, hence some extra motivation.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at in the comments, `[Out] byte[] buf` and `out byte[] buf` are two completely different things for the marshaller. The first expects the caller to allocate the memory, the second expects the callee to allocate and fill the memory. Since the original declaration with `[Out]` works, I suggest you try this declaration:

```cs
[LibraryImport("tbs", EntryPoint = "Tbsip_Submit_Command",StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]
internal static partial uint Tbsip_Submit_Command(
    IntPtr context,
    uint locality,
    uint priority,
    in byte[] inBuffer,
    uint inbufferSize,
    ref byte[] outbuf,
    ref uint outBufLen
);
```

And then allocate the outbuf array before you pass it to the method. That's most likely what you've done before already, or it wouldn't have worked.

(I think you don't need any attributes on parameters, but I'm not sure about this)

Comment: Hey! Sorry to keep this hanging, I fell ill for almost a full week. I tried to this, but it won't compile. The reason is the same a noted in the original question "Error SYSLIB1051". I also upvoted away the "-1", I don't know why it was given, but I appreciate the time you gave to consider this.

Comment: @Veksi I haven't used this LibraryImport to often yet, so it's still a bit of guessing for me, too. Try with adding `[MarshalUsing(CountElementName = "outBufLen")]`.

Comment: Indeed, I've tried (and some others things) too. Mentioned also in the original question as some of the things I've tried and issues I've encountered. A bit as a key words too in case someone is searching answer for the same issue. I suppose this will eventually be solved. :)